# Is there a way to VLOOKUP with range cell is contained in cell value

Tags: excel

I'm trying to work this (without macro), of course not working on Apples and Peer:

- Plain text exemple : `https://pastebin.com/3L8rzxCa`
- Snip of my excel sheet: `https://imgur.com/a/kkVvqZ3`

[image]

I Want to check if a cell (that contains a list of goods) contains one value from a range (inventory) AND is present in stock.

I Tried :

- VLOOKUP with wildcard (not working since fruit in stock should be contained in the Basket list, not the other way around)
- Countif : works to check if cell contains indiviual value from range, but can't check if "in stock"

Maybe a CSE formula I can't craft?

I hope it's understandable... Thanks in for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND($A$2:$A$5,B8))*($B$2:$B$5="Yes")),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

The above assumes that the fruits in the list provided are all present in the list of fruits in stock.

The above also assumes that a `Yes` is expected as long as at least one fruit is in stock out of the provided list of fruits.

If a `No` is expected if any one of the fruits in the provided list is missing, then you could use the following:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND($A$2:$A$5,B8))*($B$2:$B$5="Yes"))=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND($A$2:$A$5,B8))),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice @Jerry, much simpler than mine. +1 (allthough I wonder, what happens if I change Apple, Pear, into ApplePie, Pear. Would still show Yes, right?)

Comment: @JvdV Yea, if a fruit can be a substring of another fruit, then we'll have issues ^^;

Comment: Working :) Thank you so much for clean solution ! That's life saving for me.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on a simple example you could try something like:

```
=IF(AND(MATCH(E4,$A$3:$A$6,0)>0,MATCH(E4,$A$12:$A$15,0)>0),INDEX($B$12:$B$15,MATCH(E4,$A$12:$A$15,0)),"")
```

[image]