# Comparing two arrays - Horizontal vs Vertical

Tags: excel, excel-formula

***What is the case***

I'm trying to compare two arrays. For simplicity sake let's assume we want to know how often the values of one array exist in the other array.

My referenced/lookup array data sits in `A1:A3`

```
Apple
Lemon
Pear
```

My search array is NOT in the worksheet, but written `{"Apple","Pear"}`

***Problem***

So to know how often our search values exists in the lookuparray we can apply a formula like:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(range1=range2))}
```

However, `{=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Pear"}=A1:A3))}` produces an error. In other words the lookup array wasn't working as expected.

What did work was using `TRANSPOSE()` function to create a horizontal array from my data first using `{=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Pear"}=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)))}` resulting in the correct answer of 2!

It seems as though my typed array is automatically handled as an horizontal array, and my data obviously was originally vertical.

To test my hypotheses I tried another formula:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Pear"}={"Apple","Lemon","Pear"}))}
```

Both are typed arrays, so with above logic it would both be horizontal arrays, perfectly able to work without using `TRANSPOSE()`, however this returns an error! `#N/A`

Again `{=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Pear"}=TRANSPOSE({"Apple","Lemon","Pear"})))}` gave a correct answer of 2.

***Question***

Can someone please explain to me:

- The reasoning why horizontal can't be compared to vertical arrays.
- Why a typed array would automatically be handled as horizontal
- Why in my test of the hypotheses the second typed array was handled as vertical.

I'm really curious, and would also be happy to be linked to appropriate documentation as so far I have not been able to find any.

This might be an easy one to answer, though I can't seem to get my head around the logic.

Comment: Just saying, this is a vertical array: `{"Apple";"Lemon";"Pear"}` (notice the delimiter difference)

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, my system delimiter is semi-colon since I'm using the Dutch application. Could this be causing my problem? Also, shouldn't `{=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Pear"}={"Apple","Lemon","Pear"}))}` be equal type or arrays? Any thought on why that wouldn't work?

Comment: I've been trying to find a proper term for this, but I haven't been able to. I'm not sure if your question was a direct subsequence of [this recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55915487/1578604), but the closest thing I found seems to be [Outer Product Matrix Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#Definition_(matrix_multiplication)). I personally got to learn how it works via trial and error and playing around with it, so I can't really give a full detailed explanation of how it works nor why it works like this.

Comment: Also about the delimiter, perhaps yes. In the english version, commas are used to delimit columns and semicolons to delimit rows, so `{1,2;3,4;5,6}` is a 3 row matrix with 2 columns. Maybe the delimiters are switched in the dutch version?

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, no it has actually been a subsequence from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55864340/is-there-a-way-to-vlookup-with-range-cell-is-contained-in-cell-value/55864925#55864925) question where I seemed to confuse myself and have been trying to figure it out the past few days, unsuccesfully. However the question linked by you seems to match this issue perfectly aswell. I tried to play around with delimiters, but it seemed to make no difference unfortunatelly. To me this behavior is a mystery :)

Comment: A simple thing you could try is to use `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:C3*1)` and use the [evaluate function in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k55Ly.png) (I'm not sure if you can see it well, but you see the array becomes `{0,0,0;0,0,0}`, which tells me `,` delimits a column and `;` delimits a row.

Comment: Actually, I think the function is [performing fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb0Ec.png) (although `;` is for delimiting columns it seems). So it's only because of 1 `#N/A` that you are getting `#N/A` as a result. This error arises because excel does not have anything to compare to when one of the arrays reached its end but the other one still has more elements that require an operation to be worked on.

Comment: @Jerry, it would come down to [this](https://imgur.com/xFQ7j0f) where `;` would delimit a row and I'm unsure what delimits the columns. However, even so, I still don't know when both delimiters would be the same, the arrays would be treated differently.

Comment: @Jerry, that would make sense! So that would mean you have to always compare vertical to horizontal to make it work? And is this the mechanism that would trigger excel to check every item in the first array against all items in the other one? And would that mean that on your machine `{=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple";"Pear"}={"Apple","Lemon","Pear"}))}` returns the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, so when I do this, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPSn1.png) as result [results are obtained by comparing in this order: apple=apple, apple=lemon, apple=pear; pear=apple, pear=lemon, pear=pear], (this becomes 2 in the end which should be pretty obvious from the picture I think). And it seems like pipe `|` delimits the columns, though it looks weird to me lol

Comment: Right, so you have to compare vertical against horizontal to make it work! Even though that logic is still a little vague (why can't excel figure out I'm trying to compare all items against eachother), I think you helped out a lot, thanks. Care to write as answer? Edit: I tried the pipe symbol without success. So still a little lost on that part :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone please explain to me:
>
> - The reasoning why horizontal can't be compared to vertical arrays.

This is actually possible, and you can also compare horizontal arrays with other horizontal arrays.

The reason you have been getting the error is because of the mismatch in the length of the array. Consider the following arrays:

[image]

Doing `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B3:D3=F3:G3))` is the same (on excel's english version, I'm not 100% sure on the delimiters on other versions) as `=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Lemon","Pear"}={"Apple","Pear"}))` and results in `=SUMPRODUCT(--(Apple=Apple, Lemon=Pear, Pear=???))`, that is the nth element of the first array is compared to the nth element of the second array, and if there is nothing to match --the 3rd element in the 1st array is Pear but there is no 3rd element for the 2nd array-- then you get `N/A`.

When you compare two arrays, one vertical and one horizontal, excel actually 'expands' the final array. Consider the following (1row x 3col and 2row x 1col):

[image]

Doing `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B3:D3=F3:F4))` is the same as `=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Lemon","Pear"}={"Apple";"Pear"}))` and results in `=SUMPRODUCT(--(Apple=Apple, Lemon=Apple, Pear=Apple; Apple=Pear, Lemon=Pear, Pear=Pear))`. Basically it feels like Excel expanded the two arrays like this (3col x 2row):

[image]

This 'expansion' only happens when one array is 1 row high and the other is 1 column wide I believe, so if you take arrays that have something different, then excel will go back to trying to compare an element with 'nothing' to give N/A (you can use the Evaluate Formula feature under Formula tab to help):

[image]

So essentially excel is getting something a bit similar to this, where the first array is multiplied to the second array, giving the result array:

[image]

But since the last row and last column involve blanks, you get N/A there.

> - Why a typed array would automatically be handled as horizontal

In your question, it would seem that `,` delimit rows, so with `=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Pear"}=A1:A3))` you are observing similar to the comparison of two rows in my first example, while with `=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Pear"}=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)))`, you are getting the 'expansion' occurring.

As stated in the comments, on the English version of excel, `,` delimits columns and `;` delimits rows, as can be observed in this simple example where I supply an array with 2 rows and 3 columns, excel shows `{0,0,0;0,0,0}`:

[image]

> - Why in my test of the hypotheses the second typed array was handled as vertical.

`TRANSPOSE` simply switches an array from vertical to horizontal (and vice versa), but depending on what you are trying to do, you'll get different results as per the first part of my answer, so you'll either have `N/A` when excel cannot match an item of an array with another item of the other array, or 'expansion' of the two arrays that results in a bigger array.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explaination. As it seems, arrays of different sizes have to be compared horizontal vs vertical, and the `TRANSPOSE` function could be changed into using the proper delimiters for column and row. I now see where my logic went wrong, however one thing still bugs me. As per comments, it seems my delimiter for column should be the `|`, however replacing `,` by this pipe symbol in the working formula would not get my formula to work. It seems I have to resort to using `TRANSPOSE()`.

Comment: @JvdV Yes, I unfortunately don't know how to make that one work since I only have the english version of excel. I'll trying to look for it though.

Comment: only if you can mate, it's allready been very helpfull. For your information: `{=SOMPRODUCT(--({"Apple"|"Pear"}={"Apple";"Lemon";"Pear"}))}` can't be entered as formula and Excel wants me to replace the pipe symbol. However the screenshot as per comments showed this is the appropriate symbol.

Comment: @JvdV Ok, I was able to change my excel to dutch by changing my regional settings in control panel ^^ And... [it's actually a backslash to delimit columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZZBA.png) after a few tries!

Comment: Yes it is! A tilted backslash on evaluate, how sneaky is Excel! Thank you for figuring this out.