# TEXTJOIN based on multiple columns and multiple IF conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a TEXTJOIN based on multiple columns, in this case Column B and D within a selected range (If column A = G9 and column C = H9) while ignoring items in Column D that are not in range G2:G5 (if Column D = an item in range G2:G5). Everything I try seems to result in NA#

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think you might be missing the **Cntrl+Shift+Enter** while working with arrays in TextJoin Function.

Comment: I still get errors when I use the array ctr+shift+enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" | ",TRUE,IF(A2:A17=G9,IF(C2:C17=H9,IF(D2:D17=TRANSPOSE(G2:G5),E2:E17,""))))
```

Confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Unfortunately I don't have textjoin and am unable to test myself.

To elaborate, I beleive you are needing the `TRANSPOSE()` function. Right now you are comparing a vertical range against a vertical range. This can cause problems, the `N/A#` error, due to the different size of the arrays you are comparing. I myself was confused by this behaviour and asked a question on this matter on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917978/comparing-two-arrays-horizontal-vs-vertical). The answer given was very usefull to elaborate on this Excel behaviour.

Hopefully this solves your issue :)

---

**EDIT**

I wish I could play around with `TEXTJOIN()` to help you out, but to have a temporary patch until someone actually can help you further, you could try implement some `SUBSTITUTE()` functions to catch the `FALSE` values like so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" | ",TRUE,IF(A2:A17=G9,IF(C2:C17=H9,IF(D2:D17=TRANSPOSE(G2:G5),E2:E17,""))))," | FALSE ",""),"| FALSE",""),"FALSE | ","")
```

Entered as array

Comment: Thanks, it's getting much closer than the NA#s I was getting before. It's capturing the right comments, but adding a bunch of FALSES in between:                                                       comment 1 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | comment 4 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | comment 6 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | comment 9 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE

Comment: @ChrisBak, I wish I had an Excel 2019 license to play around with TEXTJOIN() myself to get rid of those FALSE values for you. Maybe try edited answer for a temporary 'patch'

Comment: Thanks JvdV, that works pretty great: comment 1 | comment 4 | comment 6 | comment 9

Comment: I am having another strange problem when I try to use dynamic named ranges, it seems to change the range. For example, =OFFSET('ABAK data'!F$2,0,0,COUNTA('ABAK data'!$F:$F),1) will change the range formula to:   =OFFSET('ABAK data'!XEV$2,0,0,COUNTA('ABAK data'!$F:$F),1)  as soon as I hit CTR-CHIFT-ENTER and I wind up with a Value#