# Concatenating Data with Multiple Criteria Alternative to the Transpose Function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, textjoin

I'm attempting to return a string of values that match multiple sets of criteria. All of the criteria except for the one that looks to see if the value matches a key seem to be working. I believe it has something to do with combining a array formula with a OR statement.

I was able to create one formula that worked using the TRANSPOSE function however, once I dragged it down my excel prompted me with the below error message. (Assuming it is too much data to compute)

Here is the formula that worked initially:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(('Sample Check Data'!$A:$A=Solution!B3)*('Sample Check Data'!$T:$T=Solution!D3)*('Sample Check Data'!$J:$J>Solution!G3)*('Sample Check Data'!$M:$M=TRANSPOSE(Criteria!$A$2:$A$8)),'Sample Check Data'!$H:$H,""))
```

Image

[image]

As an alternative, I built this formula which continues to fail to return a #VALUE Error (The bold highlight is what's causing it to fail. I, unfortunately, can't figure out the issue. Does anyone know how to resolve?:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(**'Sample Check Data'!$M:$M=OR(Criteria!$A$2:$A$8)***('Sample Check Data'!$A:$A=Solution!B3)*('Sample Check Data'!$T:$T=Solution!D3)*('Sample Check Data'!$J:$J>Solution!G3),'Sample Check Data'!$H:$H,"NoDataFound"))
```

I found the transpose solution on this thread but it did not mention any memory issue resulting from its use. [TEXTJOIN based on multiple columns and multiple IF conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248780/textjoin-based-on-multiple-columns-and-multiple-if-conditions)

Any help or alternative solution would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

After some more trial and error I found a solution, however I'm still running into the Excel Ran Out of Resources Error.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(('Sample Check Data'!$A:$A=Solution!B3)*('Sample Check Data'!$T:$T=Solution!D3)*('Sample Check Data'!$J:$J>Solution!G3)* (('Sample Check Data'!$M:$M=Criteria!$A$2) +('Sample Check Data'!$M:$M=Criteria!$A$3)+('Sample Check Data'!$M:$M=Criteria!$A$4) +('Sample Check Data'!$M:$M=Criteria!$A$5)+('Sample Check Data'!$M:$M=Criteria!$A$6)+('Sample Check Data'!$M:$M=Criteria!$A$7)+('Sample Check Data'!$M:$M=Criteria!$A$8)),'Sample Check Data'!$H:$H,""))
```

I attempted to modify the column references from `$A:$A` to `$A$1:$A$10000` that way less computing power is required. After making this change I now receive a N/A error. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: some sample data and your updated formula will help

Comment: do not use full column references.