# SUMPRODUCT((range={"this";"that"})*(other conditions)) return N/A if some cell of range does not meet this or that

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

Data set:

```
A|B

1|a     
2|b     
3|c
```

Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B3={"a";"b"}))
```

The sumproduct return NA there. I don't get why. I want it to return 2.

If I add c to the condition it correctly returns 3.

What am I my missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing an array of size 1x3 to an array of size 1x2 which is not allowed. (If you compare two vertical arrays, they must be the same size. This is why the problem is fixed when you add `"c"` to the formula.)

You need to compare a 1x3 array to a *2x1* array.

This expression:

```
B1:B3={"a";"b"}
```

Returns:

```
{TRUE;TRUE;#N/A}
```

`SUMPRODUCT` cannot handle logical (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) values so you must add 0, multiply by 1, or perform double negative operator to change to an array of numerical values.

So... this:

```
--(B1:B3={"a";"b"})
```

Returns:

```
{1;1;#N/A}
```

Performing `SUMPRODUCT` on this will still return `#N/A` since the array contains `#N/A`.

But if you do this: (Note the comma instead of semicolon)

```
B1:B3={"a","b"}
```

Now you get:

```
{TRUE,FALSE;FALSE,TRUE;FALSE,FALSE}
```

Note this returns a 2x3 array.

Perform double negative operator and you get this:

```
{1,0;0,1;0,0}
```

Now performing `SUMPRODUCT` will return 2, as you expect.

The final formula you need is:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B3 = {"a","b"}))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a compehensive explaination about the vert vs horizontal arrays. +1

Comment: I've been to fast.
Can't use "," excel wont let me.

What's the symbol for vertical array delimiter in french ?

Comment: Without clear documentation, just like how I explained above, you should definately try the backslash. You can however find out yourself with `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B3=TRANSPOSE({"a";"b"})))` and go through evaluation. Or just leave the `TRANSPOSE` I guess.

Comment: took me time to understand what you meant.
Eventualy bruteforced it.

It was "."

Comment: @a1a1a1a1a1 Please mark one of these answers as correct by placing a checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

You'r comparing a horizontal range vs. a vertical range. However your delimiter is wrong in case of English version. Also, with the right `,` as delimiter, your comparison will return a range of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values.

Wrap your comparison in a double negative or multiply it by 1. e.g.:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B3={"a","b"}))
```

Or:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B3={"a","b"})*1)
```

This will change `TRUE` into `1` and `FALSE` into `0`, values your `SUMPRODUCT` can actually sum.

A more comprehensive explaination on why adding a "c" would work given by @Jerry on a failry similar question I once had can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917978/comparing-two-arrays-horizontal-vs-vertical)

Comment: Not downvoting, just commenting, this is only half the problem. OP is comparing a vertical array to vertical array. Needs to compare vertical array to horizontal array.

Comment: `B1:B3` is a vertical array of size 3. `{"a";"b"}` is a vertical array of size 2. Comparing them will result in `#N/A`. Semicolon must be changed to comma.

Comment: Are you using a non-English version of Excel? I recall that in some languages semicolons are regularly used instead of commas. In English version of Excel, semicolons are used for vertical arrays.

Comment: See my post, with pictures to prove, using comma instead of semicolon is necessary.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889, Ah, yes, we mean the same, my system equivalent to the semicolon is a very annoying backslash trapping me in this mistake. Edited the answer accordingly. Excuses for mixing these up.

Comment: No problem, glad we cleared it up. +1 Out of curiosity, does your version of Excel use comma for vertical arrays?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889, no it uses a semicolon. The very strange thing is that by default the horizontal delimiter is a backslash, with no clear documentation to be found. Only been able to find this out through trial and error through evaluation which made it look like a pipe symbol as per linked question in my answer. Very frustrating :)