# Horizontal vs Vertical array delimiters - International

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Following up on an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917978/comparing-two-arrays-horizontal-vs-vertical) I had about horizontal vs vertical arrays, I have a question about it's respective delimiters.

***Problem definition:***

Hereby an example of an incorrect way of comparing two arrays:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Pear"}={"Apple","Lemon","Pear"}))}
```

The correct way, in case of an English application countrycode would be:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple","Pear"}={"Apple";"Lemon";"Pear"}))}
```

Within an English version (most likely more than just English) of Excel these delimiters would respectively be a comma `,` for horizontal arrays and a semicolon `;` for vertical ones. Plenty of online information to be found on this.

Working on a machine with a Dutch country code on it's application however, it't a complete other story. It does frustrate that my delimiters would both be different, respectively `;` and a `\`. Being able to rather simply retrieve the semi-colon it's proven to be tricky to find any documentation on these delimiters for international version.

***Workaround:***

Not knowing these delimiters up-front makes it tricky for anyone on a variety of international versions of the application to work with these type of formulas. A rather easy workaround would be to use `TRANSPOSE()`:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple";"Pear"}=TRANSPOSE({"Apple";"Lemon";"Pear"})))}
```

Going through the build-in evaluation we can then retrieve the backslash as the column seperator. Another way would be to use the [Application.International property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.international) and it's `xlColumnSeparator` and `xlRowSeparator`.

***Question***

We can both find and even override the `xlDecimalSeparator` and `xlThousandsSeparator` through Excel (File > Options > Advanced), or VBA (`Application.DecimalSeparator = "-"`) but where can we find:

- A place to actually see which `xlRowSeparator` and `xlColumnSeparator` are used within your own application, other than the workarounds I described. Looking for an interface similar to thousands and decimal seperator and/or official MS-documentation.

Furthermore (not specifically looking for this), is there:

- A place to override them just like the decimal and thousand seperators
- If not through Excel interfaces, can we brute-force this somehow through VBA?

I'm very curious if official documentation is present, and/or if the above can be done.

Comment: @JvdV, you don't want to change the regional and Language settings on the computer?

Comment: @AAA Ideally I don't, as I simply can't through server constraints. However, under these settings is there an actual vertical list separator other than only a list delimiter?

Comment: no...but I am still checking. For not, the only way I see to build a truly international app is to check the `Application.International ` and maybe do some `Replace` based on the version you originally designed the Sheet.

Comment: @AAA  the fact we can't see the application it's delimiters in some interface baffles me, I'm sure trial and error is not the way to find out about a column delimiter? I'm still hoping I'm simply looking at the wrong places.

Comment: @JvdV, why don't you simply put the values in a sheet? This way you won't have to deal with the delimiters.

Comment: How are you actually inputting the array constants into the worksheet cells?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld,I'm not specifically entering data in the worksheet, I'm merely asking the question out of curiosity sake. There have been instances I ran into this problem building formulas, but seen others struggle to find the right delimiter too. Therefor asked the question to know where we can actually retrieve these delimiters as for the English version it seems so straightforward. Just no documentation to be found (that I know of) other than some VBA-tricks.

Comment: One `VBA` trick, that could be language neutral, would be to construct the array using a VBA function.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld In instances I did need it in a formula I wanted to compare different sized arrays, just like in the simplified example above. The aha moment I'm looking for is the way to change around these delimiters in the application, either through interfaces (like the decimal and thousand delimiters can be changed) or hardcoded in VBA. If it is even possible. If not possible I'm at it's least interested in where we can find these delimiters in Excel, as I can't believe Excel let us in the dark and find out ourselves through trial and error.

Comment: If you are entering the array constant directly on the worksheet, you'll need look up the delimiter (either in some chart or by using the Application.International method) and then your worksheet will only work with that particular set of delimiters.

Comment: @JvdV Actually to look them up in Excel, you can write a little VBA macro to just return those separators.

Comment: I don't think think this can be done using Excel only (but you might be able to change default delimiters by changing your system settings. I know this isn't what you're asking though.) It is indeed annoying that language-specific delimiters are used in different versions of Excel. [It often results in confusion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57091759/sumproductrange-thisthatother-conditions-return-n-a-if-some-cell-o#comment100709570_57093452) :)

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889, exactly why I started this thread :)

Comment: Hahaha I figured. As soon as I saw that you posted this question, I thought to myself, "this must be because of that discussion about delimiters on that question from the other day!" But yea... this is a very annoying problem. At my job I often work with German subcontractors. We use CSV files a lot, and their default is semicolons, my default is commas. So we have to do some extra work. (Usually we use Notepad++ and replace all commas with semicolons or vice versa.)

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 the really odd thing is, where is the Ms documentation on these delimiters!

Comment: I'm confused about the entire premise. If the search array comes [as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55917978/11683) with commas/semicolons, and you are building a formula out of it to put it in a cell, then why do you care about local separators? `Formula` always works in en-us. And if you are not building a formula to put in a cell, how do you utilise the pre-built string of `{"Apple","Pear"}`?

Comment: @GSerg, thanks for looking into this. I'm not so much looking to specifically change these delimiters (please refer to my question's bottom alinea), I really just want to know where they are documented, if they have a place like the thousand and decimal delimiters, and if so, can we change them (not a requirement). I have not been able to find any cridible/official documentation on this. They have caused confusion more than once.

Comment: You can change them , but you absolutely [should not](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873). What is the actual problem you are solving?

Comment: @GSerg, the problem is simple: I don't want to use transpose in this formula: `{=SUMPRODUCT(--({"Apple";"Pear"}=TRANSPOSE({"Apple";"Lemon";"Pear"})))}`, so how do I beforehand know the right delimiter, in my case the backslash. Changing them is just a curiosity. The actual use in formulas has come into play more than once. I know about `Application.International property` but in my head it makes sence MS has got official documentation so all users of their application can use these delimiters. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: The easiest way I know to check delimiters is to type `=a1:b2` in formula bar and press F9, if someone is not sure about the order might go for `=a1:a2` and `=a1:b1` separately. Btw. changing the decimal separator will also change array separator in many cases.

Comment: No, it's not any clearer now. If you are entering the formulas programmatically, then like I said before, you do not need to know the current delimiter. `.Formula` always uses the en-us delimiters. If you are entering the formulas manually, then you are supposed to know the delimiters because they should be natural for your language, and if you don't, then you can consult `Application.International` - and again, it is not clear what it is the problem with using that. `Application.International(xlColumnSeparator)` tells you the answer, you know about it, yet it is not good for some reason?

Comment: @GSerg, I'm unsure how to make it clearer to you. I know how to pull of some VBA or formula steps to retrieve the delimiter. I'm not programming a macro. I'm just interested in a place that documents these delimiters for international Excel versions. These delimiters might come natural to you, they don't always do so in other versions. While other delimiters seem to have documentation, these don't. Also, if I'm looking for something that simply doesn't excist, than that can also be an answer. Appreciate your thoughts nonetheless.

Comment: So you are looking for a table of all locales, with respective separators listed for each. I doubt one exists. Some of this information comes from the OS settings, so you can look it up in the control panel (e.g. decimal dot, thousands separator, list separator). Some, however, is indeed chosen by Excel, seemingly randomly. I would go to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAAEAAA=Office_2013_-_Office_2019 and expand the "Create one-dimensional and two-dimensional constants" node...

Comment: ... Then start changing the `en-us` portion of the URL to the locales you want to learn about, e.g. `nl-nl` for Dutch. Unfortunately, the code will remain in English because the article is auto-translated, but the screenshots will show the correct separators for rows and columns.

Comment: You could make a simple macro enabled workbook with a module containing a VBA function that returns the locale values from Application.Internationalizaition. Make a table on the worksheet that lists the values you are interested in seeing. Then on any system you need the values for just open that workbook as reference. Pretty sure there is no override at the application level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not claiming this is the right answer, but with the help from comments from other users, maybe the below can clarify things a bit:

With no sign of any official documentation on this matter, and seemingly random row and column delimiters @Gserg showed a trick to retrieve information for any LCID using these unique id's on [MS office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAAEAAA=Office_2013_-_Office_2019) under *"Create one-dimensional and two-dimensional constants"*. While this is MS office support information, the delimiters you see there are FALSE. They might come up as `.` a `,` a `;` a `:` a `\` or even a `|`. You get this results by changing the LCID from the URL to a LCID of interest, e.g.: `fr-fr`.

Although there are about 600 different LCID's they all get redirected to a default LCID. With the help of @FlorentB. we discovered that not only the MS office support documentation is wrong, it seems that these delimiters are not that random after all. Looking at [countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) using a decimal point, they use the `,` as a column delimiter (a horizontal array) and a `;` as a row delimiter (a vertical array). Countries using a decimal comma however use a `\` as a column delimiter and a `;` for rows respectively.

Changing the system country settings, checking all default LCID's in Excel, we ended up with the matrix below showing all row and column delimiters per default LCID:

```
| LCID  | Row | Column |
|-------|-----|--------|
| ar-sa | ;   | ,      |
| bg-bg | ;   | \      |
| cs-cz | ;   | \      |
| da-dk | ;   | \      |
| de-de | ;   | \      |
| el-gr | ;   | \      |
| en-gb | ;   | ,      |
| en-ie | ;   | ,      |
| en-us | ;   | ,      |
| es-es | ;   | \      |
| et-ee | ;   | \      |
| fi-fi | ;   | \      |
| fr-fr | ;   | \      |
| he-il | ;   | ,      |
| hr-hr | ;   | \      |
| hu-hu | ;   | \      |
| id-id | ;   | \      |
| it-it | ;   | \      |
| ja-jp | ;   | ,      |
| ko-kr | ;   | ,      |
| lt-lt | ;   | \      |
| lv-lv | ;   | \      |
| nb-no | ;   | \      |
| nl-nl | ;   | \      |
| pl-pl | ;   | \      |
| pt-br | ;   | \      |
| pt-pt | ;   | \      |
| ro-ro | ;   | \      |
| ru-ru | ;   | \      |
| sk-sk | ;   | \      |
| sl-si | ;   | \      |
| sv-se | ;   | \      |
| th-th | ;   | ,      |
| tr-tr | ;   | \      |
| uk-ua | ;   | \      |
| vi-vn | ;   | \      |
| zh-cn | ;   | ,      |
| zh-hk | ;   | ,      |
| zh-tw | ;   | ,      |
```

The apparent conclusion is that all countries use a semicolon as a row (vertical) delimiter. And depending on decimal seperator countries use a backslash or comma as a column (horizontal) delimiter within array formulas.

So even without proper MS-documentation, nor a place within the Excel interface (like thousand en decimal delimiter do have), on this matter it is apparent that knowing your country's decimal seperator will automatically mean you either use a `\` or `,` as a column delimiter.

```
| Dec_Seperator | Row | Column |
|---------------|-----|--------|
| .             | ;   | ,      |
| ,             | ;   | \      |
```

I would happily recieve more information about the above and/or presence of any correct MS office documentation to add to this.

Comment: Delimiters are not random. It is `,;` by default and `;\ `  when the decimal separator is a comma. Note that your list is incorrect. For instance, delimiters for `fr-fr` are `;\ `.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator. All the countries using a comma as decimal separator don't use a comma as column/row separator.

Comment: @FlorentB. I have edited the above after going through all these default LCID's and checking their column and row delimiters. Thanks for your help, I have mentioned it in the above.

Comment: For a German system it should be `.` for row and `;` for column

Comment: @Ike, that can't be right. That would make German the *only* LCID where semi-colon **isn't** used for a row delimiter. Can you confirm that `={0;1}` spills *horizontally*?

Comment: Sorry: I misunderstood the usage of row and column: `;` spills **vertically** resulting in a column :-/ --> https://i.imgur.com/8G9l2i6.png

Comment: Thanks for that information Ike, meaning that at least for German, the above answer seems **wrong**.  I checked by changing the LCID at the above given link and indeed for German they show the dot. However they also show a dot for French which is clearly wrong. This actually makes me re-wonder about a common rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this through native Excel (without VBA or add-ins) by querying Excel's C API, but I don't know of anywhere this is documented.

Go into Excel's Name Manager and click 'New...'. Enter a name such as `GetColumnSeparator`.

In the 'RefersTo:' box, enter the following to get the **column separator**:

```
=INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37), 14)
```

In an Excel cell, you can now enter this:

```
=GetColumnSeparator
```

and the comma (in English - or whatever symbol is in use on your machine) will be shown.

For the **row separator** you need to change the index number to 15:

```
=INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37), 15)
```

On an English machine, this will be the semicolon by default.

On machines where Excel's 'display language' is not English (meaning Excel's function names are translated), you will need a translated version of the above formula. Again I don't know of any documentation on this, so my best suggestion would be to install the English language pack, enter the formula in English, save the workbook, then revert to your original Excel language and re-open the workbook; Excel will translate the formula automatically.

Note that you will need to save the workbook as macro-enabled (e.g. `.xlsm` rather than `.xlsx`).

Sorry this is nearly three years late but I hope it helps.

Comment: Cool! Interestingly, the `GET.WORKSPACE` thing only worked when put in the Name Manager, as you suggested (not in a regular cell formula). I also wondered where the numbers 37 and 15 came from and found the answer here: https://0xevilc0de.com/excel-4-macros-get-workspace-reference/

Comment: @Nickolay: the 37 is something you need to learn by yourself; but you can be recorded about the 14 or 15 if you look in VBE (Alt+F11), start the object browser (F2) and look at the `xlApplicationInternational` enumeration: it is the list of all the code of the International fields; and there you'll learn that `xlColumnSeparator = 14` and `xlRowSeparator = 15`! As you can guess now, `GET.WORKSPACE(37)` is the XLM4 equivalent of VBA's `Application.International`.