# COUNTIF(S) in two column and get the unique count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any formula that can count in two columns and only return the unique count.
I have a table where two columns could have an "X", I want to count the "or" of this "X".
Meaning if it's in one or the other or both column(s) then count that, else don't.

Example:

```
 A       B        C
foo      X
bar               X
Doo      X        X
Boo
```

The expected result is 3 (foo, bar, Doo).
I can't do a `=COUNTIF(B:B, "X") + COUNTIF(C:C, "X")` since that will give me 4.
`=COUNTIF(B:C , "X")` returns 4.
`SUMPRODUCT((B:B="X")*(C:C="X")*1)` = 1, `SUMPRODUCT((B:C="X")*1)` = 4

Is there any formula that could count this case?

Sadly I don't have Office 365 at work

Comment: Is column A of any consequence when calculating this condition?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij No not really. There is one other column that I left out for simplicity but column A is not really relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one has Excel O365, you could try:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,(B:B="X")+(C:C="X"))))
```

If you have an older version of Excel, maybe try:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((B1:B4="X")+(C1:C4="X")>0,MATCH(A1:A4,A1:A4,0)),ROW(A1:A4))>0))
```

Not, this last formula is an CSE-entered formula in Excel prior to O365. Also, if your data starts at a different row you'd need to adjust the formula accordingly. See [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria) link that will explain how.

---

If you just want to count the rows that contain at least one "X", try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B&C:C={"X";"XX"}))
```

This would simply concatenate columns B&C and then check if the resulting value is either "X" or "XX". Depending if you do not even have headers it can be even simpler:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B&C:C<>""))
```

If you want te minus the header: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B&C:C<>""))-1`

Comment: Oh wow that formula really slows down my computer. It takes a few seconds for it to "set" the formula but sadly I can't get it to work. Perhpas it's my error. Let me try a few times more

Comment: @Andreas, note that the second has explicit range references, not whole columns! It should therefor not take such a toll on performance.

Comment: @Andreas, If understood correctly. You are counting ***unique*** values in column A right?

Comment: Well yes.. They are all unique in column A. if we turn it upside down: "count all of column A" - "count of empty rows B:C". Column A was perhaps an error of me to include. But then I would have had a hard time to show the "Boo" line.

Comment: @Andreas, your title had me believe you wanted to count unique values in column A based on *if* either column B or C, or both had an `X`. Hence why my answer is more "complicated".

Comment: @Andreas, it's completely fine. I'll leave the answer here for future reference.

Comment: @Andreas, added an alternative for you.

Comment: Works. Sorry for the edit, I thought it would count them twice.

Comment: This formula is actually also very much readable and far shorter. It took me quite some time to make it work in VBA though. Didn't know backslash was so much trouble in VBA. (not to mention figuring out it was that character that was the issue). In case anyone tries this answer and tries in VBA, replace the backslash with a comma and it will work

Comment: @Andreas, that's my bad. In my local language the backslash is the vertical delimiter. For english, that would be the semicolon. I'll edit that. Btw, it took me also a long time to realize [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57120417/9758194).

Comment: The thing is that with backslash in Excel it works fine. I have a line of VBA with `..range.formula = "=Sumproduct(.....)"`. If I take the "string" and add it to the immediate window and debug print it, then copy that to my Excel cell it works fine. But the code does not. That was a pain to debug.

Comment: @Andreas, that means you also have the backslash as the columns delimiter in your locale. See the link I shared in my previous comment. I didn't know you needed to do this through VBA, otherwise I would have advised that VBA uses the english notation. =). Nice to see you got it working now.

Comment: The issue is/was a formula. Although I could have said I needed it in VBA I would also risk a closing of the question since I effectively have two questions in the same question. And someone might come with a loop and count solution. Which is correct but not what I wanted. Translating a formula to a VBA formula shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Use concat formula in column D such that D1=CONCAT(A1,B1) , D2=CONCAT(A2,B2) and so on.

```
D1=CONCAT(A1,B1)
```

Then use counta function on column D to count all cells that are not blank, simple as that , i hope.

```
=COUNTA(D:D)
```

Does that help you ?

OR Alternatively Try,

```
= COUNTIFS(B:B, "X",C:C, "") + COUNTIFS(B:B, "",C:C, "X") + COUNTIFS(B:B, "X",C:C, "X")
```

Comment: It's definitely a possible solution. Not as simple as I was hoping but it could work.

Comment: =COUNTIFS(B:B, "X",C:C, "") + COUNTIFS(B:B, "",C:C, "X") , if this helps , i will add this to answer as well

Comment: edited to take that in consideration, please mark as answer if it works for you.

Comment: First solution is useful for relatively large number of columns. Second solution is logically more clear if its for just 2 columns..

Comment: I will go with this solution. The only reason being the readability of the formula. I have noticed that understanding what you wrote a few weeks ago is very important.

Answer (score 2):

If you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd> then can use `FILTER()` function with `COUNTA()`.

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A4,(B1:B4="x")+(C1:C4="x")))
```

[image]

Comment: I do not have 365, But I'm quite sure that would work

Answer (score 2):

See if below implementation of `SUMPRODUCT` is useful for you.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",B2:B5&C2:C5,1)))`

Or it needs to be tight and avoid issues like wild card matches etc. then you can also try:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(((B2:B5="X")+(C2:C5="X"))>0))`

Answer (score 0):

This might be simpler.
=COUNTIF(B:C,"X")-COUNTIFS(B:B,"X",C:C,"X")

It counts the total of all and then subtracts count of rows with both columns filled.

Comment: That will return 1 since only one line has "X"  "X"