# How do I create an array in excel using array notation {1,2;3,4} like you can in google sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Google Sheets I can create any array using [array notation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20create%20your,of%20data%20in%20an%20array). For example by entering `={1,2;3,4}`,  I create the following array:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

In Excel I´ve managed to use the same notation but only to create a one-dimensional array (i.e. a single column):

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| 1,2 |
| 3,4 |

Can I achieve the former in Excel?

Comment: If that doesn't work for you in Excel, then your regional settings must not use a comma as an array separator. What are your regional settings? (Perhaps try a space or backslash as the separator)

Comment: I imagine that's simply because your version of Excel uses the comma as decimal separator. Hence, for you, `1,2` is being interpreted as 1 and 2 tenths. You need to find out what the separator for horizontal arrays is for your version of Excel.

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed the regional settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel you can create arrays using almost same notation but:

1. Use comma (or semicolon depending on regional settings) to separate values of same row.
2. Use inverted slash `\` to separate columns.

So let's make an array like this:

```
{1;3\2;4}
```

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

Just a few examples using INDEX:

`=INDEX({1;3\2;4};1;1)` will return value from row 1 and column 1 so it returns 1.

`=INDEX({1;3\2;4};1;2)` from row 1 and column 2 so it returns 3!!

Anyways, this notation is not used often in Excel. Normally arrays are used trough VBA and that would be a different question.

**UPDATE:** Looks like both separators depend on regional settings so maybe you need to figure this out. Thanks to @Jvdv for [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171247/9199828)

**UPDATE 2:**: Thanks to @JosWolley for this:

If one isn't sure what the separators are for their version of Excel, it's quite easy to find out. Simply enter the formula `=A1:B2` in cell C1 and then go into the formula bar, highlight the entire formula and press F9. For English-language versions this produces `{0,0;0,0}` (with `A1:B2` **empty**)

In spanish version like mine is this:

[image]

Comment: FYI **both** separators depend on regional settings.

Comment: @Rory Adding this info to question. Thanks! My regional settings are spanish. Do you know which would be the \ equivalent in english settings?

Comment: For the UK, the OP's original formula would have worked as posted.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, this had me thinking too a long time ago before I became more familiar with these local dependent separators. You can find some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171247/9758194). In short, assuming dynamic arrays (thus spill effect) `={1\2;3\4}` would probably work for OP.

Comment: @JvdV very interesting post. I did not know that. I'm adding it to my answer as a source

Comment: Notice how you have got the row/column mixed up currently. As per my previous comment `={1\2;3\4}` will work most likely.

Comment: @JvdV `{1\2;3\4}` raises an error on spanish settings. You mean in UK settings?

Comment: Do you have ms365? In that case `={1\2;3\4}` would be the correct answer to OP's question on how to write out the array notation.  This should not error out since the backslash is the delimiter for columns, and semi-colon the delimiter for rows. These are the same delimiters for my Dutch locale settings. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5ZfM.png) screenshot. Note how your current answer got the rows and columns mixed up compared to what OP is looking for?

Comment: If one isn't sure what the separators are for their version of Excel, it's quite easy to find out. Simply enter the formula `=A1:B2` in cell `C1` and then go into the formula bar, highlight the entire formula and press F9. For English-language versions this produces `{0,0;0,0}` (with `A1:B2` empty).

Comment: @JvdV I'm using Excel 2007. I see your point but notice how the table of my answer is different than OP's table. I changed so position 1,2 returns 3 correctly.

Comment: @JosWoolley That's impressive!!! I did not know that. Let me add it to the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Microsoft-365 then could use `VSTACK()`, `HSTACK()`. Try this-

```
=VSTACK({1,2},{3,4})
```

Or using both `VSTACK()` & `HSTACK()`.

```
=VSTACK(HSTACK(1,2),HSTACK(3,4))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this would work for the OP, for the same reason the original formula wouldn't work. The comma is clearly not the correct separator.

Comment: @Rory Then OP need to just adjust the separator.

Comment: I know - which makes this answer overly complicated. ;)

Comment: @Rory Yes, you are correct.