# Excel Nested IF INDEX MATCH Function

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, index-match

I need to find out if various strings are in either of two columns, based on the rows in which column B:B equal a given value. When found in one of the two columns I want it to return "rejected".

Initially I only needed to search in one column and therefore used a simple Search Index Match Formular imbedded into a if Statement. This works perfectly fine.

`=if(SEARCH({"neg", "negativ", "negative", "negatives", "Bonität"},index(Input_Jira!$B$1:$N$2000,MATCH("*"&G90&"*",Input_Jira!B:B,0),2)),"rejected","")`

To include the second column I added the same if search index match logic for the case the first if statement is false:

`=if(SEARCH({"neg", "negativ", "negative", "negatives", "Bonität"}, index(Input_Jira!$B$1:$N$2000,MATCH("*"&G90&"*",Input_Jira!B:B,0),13)),"rejected",if(SEARCH({"neg", "negativ", "negative", "negatives", "Bonität"},index(Input_Jira!$B$1:$N$2000,MATCH("*"&G90&"*",Input_Jira!B:B,0),2)),"rejected",""))` 
This function gives me a value error although the separate part of the functions work perfectly fine.

Comment: A small note, but why are you searching for either of these values when just searching 'neg' should include all other possibilities (besides "Bonität") since they contain this specific substring. A 2nd note, I'd nest your `SEARCH()` in an `ISNUMBER()` to avoid possible errors. 3rd, when creating a matrix you'd probably need to nest this in `MMULT()` or `BYROW()` to test each row for a truthy (if that is your goal here in the 1st place). If the latter is not what you are after, then just nest it in `OR()`. For example `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"neg", "bonität"},...........`

Comment: Good point with the substring. I will look into your other suggestions, thanks. I never heard of MMULT() or BYROW().

Comment: But is there any reason why the nesting like I did it does not work? I know its not very elegant but I dont see a reason why it should not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to count if specific strings appear in a range, just use COUNTIF combined with an array:

[image]

E2 = `=SUM(COUNTIF($A$1:$B$12;{"a","b"}))`

E3 = `=SUM(COUNTIF($A$1:$B$12;{"e";"f"}))`

E4 = `=SUM(COUNTIF($A$1:$B$12;{"a";"b"}))`

If the result is zero means there is no match at all (Second case). You can combine this with an IF statement to do whatever you need. Also, COUNTIF can be used with wildcars in case you want partial matches.

About array notation, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75864218/9199828)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, I cannot simply look up if the columns contain the strings and the count them and look if the sum is zero. I need to look if the columns contain one of the strings, based on where rows of column B:B equal the value "*"&G90&"*". That is what I need the Index Match for. I will update it in the description.