# Make a summation in Excel by several criteria

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

There is a table with data:

[image]

We want the numbers in the third column to add up when the value in the first column was "Red" or "White" and the value in the second column was "One" or "Two". Under such conditions, the sum should be 14 (1, 3, 4 and 6 lines are added). I tried this formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(F$36:F$43;E$36:E$43;{"One";"Two"};D$36:D$43;{"Red";"White"}))
```

But for some reason the result of this formula is 7 instead of 14. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question. It needs to be like this in order to return `14` instead of `7`.

[image]

---

```
=SUM(
    SUMIFS(
        F$36:F$43,
        E$36:E$43, {
            "One";
            "Two"
        },
        D$36:D$43, {
            "Red",
            "White"
        }
    )
)
```

---

To check for the multiple conditions the criteria needs to validate both `One` & `Two` for `Red` & `White` on doing it returns an array of 2x2, first gets the value of `Red` for `One` & `Two` as `{1;4}` and then for the latter as `{3;6}`

[image]

---

```
=SUMIFS(F$36:F$43,E$36:E$43,{"One";"Two"},D$36:D$43,{"Red","White"})
```

---

In your version of `Excel` it will be:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(F$36:F$43;E$36:E$43;{"One";"Two"};D$36:D$43;{"Red"."White"}))
```

---

Comment: I have tried both `"Red"."White"` and `"Red","White"` and neither work (Excel asking if I'm sure I wanted to insert a formula).

Comment: @Notus_Panda its because your regional settings is different. For Spanish version of Excel it would be `=SUMA(SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(F$36:F$43;E$36:E$43;{"One";"Two"};D$36:D$43;{"Red"."White"}))` -- here `;` returns row wise, while `.` returns column wise. And that is the reason why I always update my post with screenshots showing formula bar. Its funny sometime ago, someone downvoted me for updating images. Seriously there is no rule of law in SO that members cant update images in answers.

Comment: I'm using Dutch Excel but as I said, I already tried `{"Red"."White"}` as you suggested. For some reason it's not seeing it as a column separator :/

Comment: @Notus_Panda hold on let me share my excel with you, try opening on your end, and see what happens, also may i know what is the column separator you are using. **[Here_Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckigFynjkhQ8plqdh?e=MvwwyI)**

Comment: Ok, thanks for the share, now I know Dutch excel prefers to use `{"Red"\"White"}`, I'll add it to my list of grievances towards Dutch Excel :')

Comment: @Notus_Panda the reason the Dutch version has a different column/row separator is that numbers have a different decimal separator: `,` this is in conflict with the US separator, hence they used `;` and `/`. (Don't know the reason for other languages that differ).

Comment: Oh I know why, it's just that "\" seems like such an off-pick to me, so out of the way instead for example what Mayukh actually suggested "."  which is a thousand-separator in Dutch just like "," is for English versions but maybe that gets in the way of formulas (`SUMIFS` = `SOMMEN.ALS` in Dutch). Even "/" would make more sense to me than "\".

Comment: @Notus_Panda you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171247/9758194) page for some clarity on the topic.

Comment: Cheers @JvdV If I was better at expressing myself, I may have stumbled upon your post myself but "separator" sadly didn't cut it for "delimiter" ^^'

Comment: For a German system it is indeed ";" and "."

Comment: It is possible to add a third dimension? And if possible, then how to do it?

Comment: @arachnoden can you provide me an example like a screenshot. Definitely possible, but let me show the screenshot with expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula with `SUMPRODUCT`:

`=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C9)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:B9,{"one";"two"},0)))*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A9,{"Red";"White"},0))))`

`(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:B9,{"one";"two"},0)))` returns per row `true` or `false`. Same for the second condition.

`*` acts as an `AND` operator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm explaining it correctly but when you use the curly brackets, you're specifying a range to which the sumif will look at the combination of them, i.e.
`SUMIFS(F1:F9;D1:D9;{"Red";"White"};E1:E9;{"One";"Two"})`
Will make the combination of Red+One and White+Two = 1 | 6 (see H1:H2)
In my example I1:I2 is the result of the same formula but One and Two switched around.
(this is at least what I understood from the result, will edit if I'm proven wrong)

[image]

A possible solution would be combining these two formulas in your final Sum formula:

`=SUM(SUMIFS(F$36:F$43;E$36:E$43;{"One";"Two"};D$36:D$43;{"Red";"White"})+SUMIFS(F$36:F$43;E$36:E$43;{"Two";"One"};D$36:D$43;{"Red";"White"}))`

This explains more why you got the result you had and a circumventing solution. I'm sure there's a better/cleaner way but I'll leave that for the more advanced excel-formula users.

Comment: Two `SUMIFS()` not needed here, you can actually do it with one.